# Users are unable to approve a one way relationship

Tags: users

I've set up a one way relationship with the [User Relationships](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_relationships) module When one user requests a relationship to another user, the table that should allow the other user to approve/deny the request has no operations automatically populated.

To be more specific lets say this is a Manager relationship to an employee. Where User A is the manager and User B is the employee. User A requests to be User B's Manager. User B receives the request and follows the link to the page where he/she would normally approve the relationship.(example.com/user/[uid]/relationships/received) When User B arrives on the page there is a table showing the request, but under the Operations column there is nothing in the cells.

I initially thought this was a permissions issue, but when I looked it appears that both users have the permissions they should need to accomplish this.

For reference I'm using version 7.x-1.0-alpha5 of the User Relationships module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this actually was a permissions issue. In order for someone to be able to accept a relationship request, they also need permission to make the request.

In order to accomplish what I needed I also had to enable the "User Relationship Implications" module.